# Unable to bind emphasize key in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

I am trying to create new keybindings for quickly italicizing and bold-facing the text in org-mode. By default, `org-emphasize` function is provided by org-mode for this. I'm leveraging that for my case.

For example, this is the keybinding for bold-facing the text:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "s-b") (
                      lambda () 
                      (interactive) 
                      (org-emphasize '*) 
                      ))
```

However, when I run the keybinding, it throws the error:

```
org-emphasize: Wrong type argument: characterp, *
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version: you need to give `org-emphasize` a *character*, so
change your function to read

```
(org-emphasize ?\*)
```

The docstring for `org-emphasize` says that:

> (org-emphasize &optional CHAR)
>
> Insert or change an emphasis, i.e. a font like bold or italic.
>   If there is an active region, change that region to a new emphasis.
>   If there is no region, just insert the marker characters and position
>   the cursor between them.
>   CHAR should be the marker character.  If it is a space, it means to
>   remove the emphasis of the selected region.
>   If CHAR is not given (for example in an interactive call) it will be
>   prompted for.

You have passed a
[*symbol*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Type.html#Symbol-Type)
to `org-emphasize` rather than a
[*character*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Character-Type.html),
which is what you need to pass to it.